# ...tirade of frightening Russian

Tags: word-usage, word-meaning, sentence-meaning

The owner of the bar had had enough. He exploded into a tirade of frightening Russian which nobody understood.

1. Is it clear that it's frightening for the people he shouts at or should I rephrase the sentence?
2. Would using "terrifying" be a better choice?

Comment: _A frightening tirade of/in Russian_ might make the sense clearer. Whether you use _terrifying_ instead is up to you; this forum doesn't give writing advice.

Answer (score -1):

*A frightening tirade in Russian* would be preferable.

> 1. Is it clear that it's frightening for the people he shouts at

Yes.

> Would using "terrifying" be a better choice?

- "Terrifying" is stronger than "frightening". Do you intend to say "*extremely* frightening"?
- "Terrifying tirade" is alliteration.  In a sentence like this one, my personal preference would be to avoid that, because it sounds like a joke. Others may disagree, and even seek out such word play.